# foo() = 42; <- How can this be possible?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the differences between pointer variable and reference variable in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-pointer-variable-and-reference-variable-in-c)

I was reading an article on rvalues in order to understand universal references from the new C++ Standard and found the following as an example of lvalue

```
// lvalues:
//
int i = 42;
i = 43; // ok, i is an lvalue
int* p = &i; // ok, i is an lvalue
int& foo();
foo() = 42; // ok, foo() is an lvalue
int* p1 = &foo(); // ok, foo() is an lvalue
```

What does `int& foo();` mean here?

Comment: A function that returns a reference to an int...

Comment: It's a function declaration.

Comment: just define it somethere

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Say the body of foo was this:

```
int & foo()
{
   static int i = 0;
   return i;
}
foo() = 30;
```

That would set the static int, i, to 30;

A more practical example is a class returning a reference to itself

```
class foo
{
public:
   foo() {}

   foo& addString() {
      /* AddString */ 
      return *this;
   }

   foo& subtractSomething() { 
      /* Subtract Something */ 
      return *this; 
   }
}
```

Then use it like:

```
foo f;
f.addString().subtractSomething();
```

class operators do this - so you can do this:

```
foo a, b c;

foo d = a+b+c;
```

Where the + operator is defined as:

```
foo & operator+(const foo& f)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
int& foo();
```

Declares a function that returns a reference to an `int`. You can see it as similar to

```
int* foo();
```

Except that the return value cannot be null.

The syntax is a bit different, though, since `int* foo();` would be used as `*(foo()) = 42;`, and `int& foo();` as `foo() = 42`.

You can read more about references in [the FAQ.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-pointer-variable-and-reference-variable-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

`int& foo();` means that the function `foo()` returns a *reference* type. That is, its return value can be modified:

```
foo() = 42;
```

means "modify the referenced value returned by `foo`".

Answer (score 0):

You're defining a function prototype with a reference as the return value. The function returns a reference to an integer. As such its return value can be set to another value.